# Getting current time but then incrementing it?

Tags: c#, winforms

Current project: To make a time program in C# with two classes Time and ExtendedTime Time is just the normal time and ExtendedTime has the time zone.

When you start the program I need to click a button and get the current time but there is an option to change the time zone.  This in turn changes the time and also has an option to increment the time by so many hours and or minutes.

Currently, this is what my displayTime method in the Time class looks like:

```
public virtual string displayTime()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Use current time
    string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; // Use this format
    MessageBox.Show(time.ToString(format)); // Write to console

    return time.ToString(format);
}//end of displayTime
```

Which isn't bad except that everytime I call it NO MATTER WHAT it will always tell me the current time because of `DateTime.Now`

I'm not totally sure how to get around that. I'm sure there is a one time deal i can do to do this but not sure of the syntax.

Comment: What does C# (not .net) mean?

Comment: @Shan: I'm pretty sure that means "new guy".  The OP probably meant "C# (not asp.net)"

Comment: lol thanks. :P yeah i mean't just C#. Someone misunderstood me the last time i posted just C# so i tried to think ahead. :P

Comment: @Chris: I'm inclined to concur with you that he means not asp.net.  I think he's writing a winforms app. (based on his previous questions and the `MessageBox.Show` in the code sample)

Comment: @allthosemiles: If you're just manipulating a `DateTime` object, it shouldn't matter whether it's WinForms or ASP.NET.

Comment: True true sir. Just getting use to changing the time through variables and through classes is just my issue here. I've never tackled ASP personally. It's probably easier then this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the TimeSpan class to manipulate the DateTime class.  For example:

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime twoHoursLater = now + new TimeSpan(2,0,0);
 DateTime twoDaysLater = now + new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0);
```

If you're using a user-supplied time, such as one from a textbox, you can use

```
 DateTime userSuppliedTime = DateTime.Parse(myTextbox.Text);
```

Which will give you a DateTime that corresponds to whatever the user enters.  Be warned, however, that if the user types in something that the system does not recognize as valid, this will throw an exception.

Comment: I could see where that would work but using a value from a txt box to change the current time. Would that in this way? Also with the time zone as well.

Comment: Also, since i'm using 2 text boxes one for minutes and one for hours how can i parse both boxes?

Comment: You could combine the textbox strings, for example:  DateTime.Parse(myTextboxHours.Text+":"+myTextboxMinutes.Text);

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) and [DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) should suffice.

```
DateTime adjusted = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Answer (score 1):

You get current time became you have no code that manipulates that DateTime field.

To apply time zones, look into TimeZoneInfo class.

Answer (score 0):

You really should look into using the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure, which works well for this kind of thing.